# Cells disappear when scroll down in my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I scroll down in my tableView some contents of cells disappear (labels and imageViews). 
My code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [comentarios removeAllObjects];

    NSString *lookup=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my.url"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookup]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);

    for (int i=0; i<[jsonDict count]; i++) {
        Comentario *come=[[Comentario alloc] init];
        come.nick=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nick"];
        come.comment=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"];
        come.avatar=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"color"];
        [comentarios addObject:come];
    }
    [self reloadInputViews];
    [self.comentariosTableView reloadData];
}
```

and

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if( cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Display recipe in the table cell
    UIImageView *avatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] avatar]];

    UILabel *nick = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    nick.text =[[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nick];

    UILabel *comment = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    comment.text = [[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] comment];

    UIButton *sinvoto = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:103];

    UIButton *ticket = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:104];

    return cell;
}
```

I can't see the mistake, please help me.
Thank you in advance

**EDIT Nª1**
just changed this

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *comentarios;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.comenatrioTableView.delegate=self;
    self.comenatrioTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    UIImage *plus=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"megafono.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:plus style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(comenta:)];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:00.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    comentarios=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self reloadInputViews];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [comentarios removeAllObjects];
    NSString *lookup=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myURL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookup]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);

    for (int i=0; i<[jsonDict count]; i++) {
        Comentario *come=[[Comentario alloc] init];
        come.nick=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nick"];
        come.comment=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"];
        come.avatar=[[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"color"];
        [comentarios addObject:come];
    }
    [self reloadInputViews];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [comentarios count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 110;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    SimpleTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Comentario *comentario=[[Comentario alloc] init];
    comentario =[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.avatar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[comentario avatar]];
    cell.nick.text=[comentario nick];
    cell.comment.text =[comentario comment];
    return cell;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

-(void)comenta:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goComment" sender:self];
}

@end
```

and ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Comentario.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *comenatrioTableView;

@end
```

**Edit Nª3**
The proble is when I scroll down, the information of cells become nil but comentarios Array have the information.

**Edit Nª4**
here is the project https://github.com/QuimeraKoke/BANG-

Comment: Maybe the nick and the avatar in your `Comentario` is nil.

Comment: did you check my answer i m waiting for your reply

Comment: Yes, in fact before scroll down becomes nil

Comment: can you post the url too so  i could check it out

Comment: I post the url of the project on my GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of other suggestions that will improve your code.

You have to call super in `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` methods:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Instead of using:

```
Comentario *comentario = [[Comentario alloc] init];
comentario = [comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with:

```
Comentario *comentario = [comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Finally, you should check your dataSource:

```
for (int i=0; i<[jsonDict count]; i++) {
    Comentario *come = [[Comentario alloc] init];
    come.nick = [[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nick"];
    come.comment = [[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"];
    come.avatar = [[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"color"];
    [comentarios addObject:come];

    NSLog(@"nick = %@, comment = %@, avatar = %@", come.nick, come.comment, come.avatar);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Instead of using:

```
@interface Comentario : NSObject

@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *nick;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *comment;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *avatar;

@end
```

you should use:

```
@interface Comentario : NSObject

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *nick;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *comment;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *avatar;

@en
```

Your problem has been resolved.

> **Copy**
>
> copy is required when the object is mutable. Use this if you need the
>   value of the object as it is at this moment, and you don't want that
>   value to reflect any changes made by other owners of the object. You
>   will need to release the object when you are finished with it because
>   you are retaining the copy.
>
> **Weak**
>
> weak is similar to strong except that it won't increase the reference
>   count by 1. It does not become an owner of that object but just holds
>   a reference to it. If the object's reference count drops to 0, even
>   though you may still be pointing to it here, it will be deallocated
>   from memory.
>
> This is a good website to learn about strong and weak for iOS 5.
>   http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

In addition to the above problem，your constrains of the SimpleTableCell is also incorrect:
[image]

You should go to the `Main.storyboard` and check it.(In Interface Builder Select the Compact Width and Compact Height Size Class)

Answer (score 1):

The `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code you're using is pretty old.

I'd suggest creating a custom UITableViewCell class, with properties for your labels, image, and buttons.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nick;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *comment;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *sinvoto;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *ticket;
@end
```

In your storyboard, set that cell's class to your custom tableViewCell, and connect its IBOutlets to the storyboard cell's labels, image, and buttons.  This will eliminate having to use tags.

Change the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` call to:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will always return a cell, so you will never have to check for nil.

Now you can directly set the cell's properties:

```
cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] avatar]];
cell.nick.text =[[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nick];
cell.comment.text = [[comentarios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] comment];
```

**Update:**

This line (has to do with changing the keyboard) is unnecessary and can be removed:

```
[self reloadInputViews];
```

Is there a reason why you are using a `UIViewController` (with a tableView that you added), instead of simply using a `UITableViewController?`

The `UITableViewController` knows how to adjust its insets to account for top and bottom bars (and you would set its `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `YES`).

After making [the changes that Banning suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565005/4151918), you may be ok.  I can't see any other reason why the cells would be blank after scrolling.

If it's still happening, you should post your `Comentario` class, so we can see if an issue with that code is affecting the stored data.

Comment: It works but not at all, the first and the last cell disappear anyway

Comment: Is the `comentarios` array being changed apart from viewWillAppear?  Can you update your question and add the new `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` code, so we can try to figure out why you would have a cell without any contents.  You may have to set a breakpoint and check the `Comentario` object to see if it has (nil) values for the fields, when the cell is being configured.

Comment: Yes you are right, before scroll Comentario becomes nil, its like i can't save it after scroll

Comment: If you want us to help answer why that happens, you'll have to post more code so we can try to see where the problem is.  Can you share your project on GitHub?